# If statement string comparison

Tags: bash, text-processing, csv

I'm reading a csv file with 14 values per line. I want to convert the HEX value from 10th [`f10`] value to a DEC value. In order to do this `if` the 7th [`f7`] value must hold `EnHr` or `EnSt` or `SpJb` or `Chem` or `TrTm` or `PmTm` or `BrTm` or `HyTm`

So this is a part of my code:

```
echo "Test 3 f7 is $f7"   

    if [ "$f7" == "EnHr" ] || [ "$f7" == "EnSt" ] || [ "$f7" == "SpJb" ] || [ "$f7" == "Chem" ] || [ "$f7" == "TrTm" ] || [ "$f7" == "PmTm" ] || [ "$f7" == "BrTm" ] || [ "$f7" == "HyTm" ]
        then
            echo -e "\t\t\t\t\tRAW VAL is $f10"   #print raw val
            f10=`echo "ibase=16; $f10" | bc`      #convert from HEX to Dec
            echo -e "\t\t\t\t\tinside the if loop\tSen: $f7\tVal: $f10" #reprint the converted value as DEC
            inside=$((inside+1))
    fi
```

Further when I print `echo -e "\t\t\t\t\tRAW VAL is $f10"` I can see HEX Values but in the following line the Val appears to be 0 in Dec

This is the output I get so far

```
Test 1             line count is 26
Test 2
Test 3 f7 is Chem
                                        RAW VAL is 0000
                                        inside the if loop      Sen: Chem       Val: 0
Test 4
Test 1             line count is 27
Test 2
Test 3 f7 is TrTm
                                        RAW VAL is 0019c4ef
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
                                        inside the if loop      Sen: TrTm       Val:
Test 4
Test 1             line count is 28
Test 2
Test 3 f7 is PmTm
                                        RAW VAL is 000b57bf
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
                                        inside the if loop      Sen: PmTm       Val:
Test 4
Test 1             line count is 29
Test 2
Test 3 f7 is BrTm
                                        RAW VAL is 00022d51
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
                                        inside the if loop      Sen: BrTm       Val:
Test 4
Test 1             line count is 30
Test 2
Test 3 f7 is HyTm
                                        RAW VAL is 00004ff9
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
                                        inside the if loop      Sen: HyTm       Val:
Test 4
```

The `Test 1-4` values are there so I can see where the code is. Just simple echos no real significance. These are my concerns:

**Q1:** How can I eliminate `(standard_in) 1: syntax error` where is it coming from?

**Q2:** Also as from the output why isn't the raw data hex value being converted to decimal?

Comment: For printing ( in the line with the comment  `#reprint the converted value as DEC`) you have used `$10` instead of `$f10` , which is why you see a 0

Comment: @AmitKumar thanks for pointing that out - I saw my typo as well - updated the question....

Comment: Below you said 100k lines - are you pulling this in with a `while ... read ...; do if ...; fi` or something? If so, then your completion time could be dramatically improved over the answer I've given, but in order to do so I'd need to see an actual input sample.

Comment: @mikeserv it is indeed above 100k lines. Thats the CSV file anyway.. Here is a [sample](http://codeshare.io/WMQiD) of the data format - I just placed an arbitrary amount of lines. My code is essentially a `while read` and it takes the timestamp and finds a matching time stamp in a php table - extracts the sensor and machine, if these 3 (timestampe sensor machine) match then it compares the values (php vs timestamp)

Comment: @mikeserv *Errartum*: "...it compares the value derived from the php table and from the  __csv__ file"

Comment: Sorry, I guess I must have missed these in my inbox or something. How do you mean *essentiallý* a `while...read`? Is it actually processed in php then? How do you get the php table data? However it is done, I'm envisioning replacing the whole thing with `grep|sed|dc` though I can imagine it might be done with just `sed|dc` or even `awk` alone. It is my belief that applying the three filters would be quicker - at least on a multicore system - but I can't swear to it.

Comment: @mikeserv By essentially, I mean fundamentally the codes back bone is a while read loop. All the ifs and cases happen in side this loop. The code reads a csv file containing 110,000+ lines and the comparisons are done each time a line is read. I'm looking at using regex, but I'm not that proficient with regex....

Comment: I can help, if you like. The case statement below would already work for `grep -E` if `$f7` were its own line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

POSIXly you can get the decimal value of a hex number like:

```
hex=10
echo "$((0x$hex))"
```

---

```
16
```

And you *really* don't need to do all of those `[` tests `]`. I think the following should work:

```
case $f7 in
(EnHr|EnSt|SpJb|Chem|[BT]rTm|PmTm|HyTm)
    printf "\t\t\t\t\t%s%b"       \
       "HEX VALUE is" ":\t$f10"   \
       '' "inside case loop.\t\t" \
       Sen ":\t$f7"               \
       Val ":\t$((!(inside+=1)|0x$f10))"
esac
```

Comment: would that speed the code up a bit? because I'm processing over 100,000 lines of text takes about 20 minutes...

Comment: @3kstc - oh yes. Especially in that it doesn't do a `$(` command substitution subshell `)` fork for each iteration - which you should really try *not* to do in a shell loop if at all possible. Also - it's portable - and so it will work in `dash` - which is far faster even than `bash`. It's for me to say exactly that it will work without real ideas of the values, though. The `case` can definitely replace the `[ test ] || [test ] || [ test ]` for sure.

Comment: @mikeserv: Well, +1, I forgot the `0x` standard way.

Answer (score 0):

For both questions, the error came from `bc`.

`0019c4ef` is an invalid [hex number in bc](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/bc.html#tag_20_09_13_02), you need `0019C4EF` for a valid hex number:

```
echo "ibase=16; 0019C4EF" | bc
1688815
```

Because you used `bash` (also work in `ksh`, `zsh`, `mksh`, `pdksh`, `posh`), you can use `[base#]n` where *base* is a decimal number between 2 and 64:

```
$ echo "$((16#0019c4ef))"
1688815
```

In your case, just remove the assignment line using `bc`, and edit the next line:

```
echo -e "\t\t\t\t\tinside the if loop\tSen: $f7\tVal: " "$((16#$f10))"
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard in error comes from `bc`. It expects hex values in upper case. So instead of `0019c4ef` you should pass it `0019C4EF`.

The hex to dec conversion can be done using without `bc` too- see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/13280173/3935925